# .Net Core Identity How to expire "Old Reset Password Link" if new "Reset Password Link" generated?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, identityserver4, asp.net-core-identity

Using .Net Core 3.1 with Identity.
Generating Reset Password Link using below code and it's working fine. But the requirement is if user is generating 2 links one by one. For ex: *Link_1* and *Link_2* then *Link_1* should not work to reset password.

```
var code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
var resetCallbackUrl = Url.Page(
    "/Account/ResetPassword",
    pageHandler: null,
    values: new { Email = user.Email, Code = code, ReturnUrl = Input.ReturnUrl },
    protocol: Request.Scheme);
```

Please help.

Comment: It's probably easier to [change the expiry](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50841665/3181933) so that the link is relatively short-lived (e.g. 15 minutes). I wouldn't worry about someone generating two password reset links. I've been in the situation many times where the reset e-mail isn't forthcoming, so I've requested another, and after I do that the first link arrives. If the site worked in the way you have described, I would still have to wait for the second link to come before I can reset my password. This doesn't seem particularly user-friendly.

Comment: Hi @John, Currently expiration time is 24 hour as per requirement. Looking to remove/ expire/ mark invalid old Reset Password Link.

Comment: Resetting a users password should reset their security stamp, which should invalidate all existing tokens. Assuming your token provider mixes the security stamp into generated tokens...

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Any example or link for reference?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/master/src/Identity/Extensions.Core/src/UserManager.cs#L922

Comment: ResetPasswordAsync > UpdatePasswordHash > UpdateSecurityStampInternal which will generate a new security stamp (if SupportsUserSecurityStamp).

Comment: @JeremyLakeman Updating user security stamp would make any user related tokens invalid (not just password reset token). It might possible if User_A is logged-in and some other User_B can use User_A email to reset password in that case User_A will be logged-out. It can be a security hole.

Comment: The stamp is per-user, and is why users A & B can't use each other's tokens.

Comment: yes User A & B can't use each other's token but User B can request reset password link (of-course User will not receive the link) and all the User A Tokens will be invalid due security stamp change.